# Does the pressure at the bottom change when two liquids mix and don't mix?

Tags: pressure, density

[image]

My question is when these two liquids above mix and don't mix, does the pressure at the bottom change ? When they don't mix the pressure is 2hdg + 3hdg = 5hdg (d:density) But what happens when they mix ? The volume of the liquids is needed or not ? I saw someone says the pressure is equal either they mix or not. I'm confused, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing a specific density is rather handy, because it allows us to relate the volume and the mass of a substance.

But to calculate the pressure, the density isn't necessary.  What is needed is the mass.

If the fluids mix, the volume (and therefore the density) may change, but the mass does not.  The total mass remains constant.  If prior to mixing, the two fluids have mass $m$, then the pressure at the bottom of the vessel due to the fluid, assuming a straight-sided vessel with area $A$:
$$ P = \frac{mg}A$$

Note that neither the volume nor the density appear here.  As long as the mass and the shape of the container are constant, so is the pressure.

Comment: So the question was: "the pressure at the bottom", and not at any arbitrary depth ?

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Yes yes, at the bottom

Comment: it would have been better to specify this in the question... (and it might be that the different opinions you heard was about pressure elsewhere, then).

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET I didn't see any necessities for that. Also I got my answer

Comment: It's like asking "what is the velocity of water in oceans accounting for currents" when you just want it on the ocean bottom. :-) And you have your answer, but your question reminds here forever for next students looking for answers, possibly misleading them.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET OK. I changed it :)

Comment: But I don't understand this thing......If we mix them then the mass of this liquid will change as well as the density of the resulting liquid.So when we apply thr formulae that is pressure at the atmosphere+pressure inside the liquid at the depth then surely some change should be coming?

Comment: @Abhinav, mass doesn't change when they mix.  Since the formula I listed doesn't depend on density, we don't care how the density might change.

Comment: @BowlOfRed mass doesn't change when they mix.....can you tell me about this because I am having hard time understanding this

Comment: @Abhinav, mass is a constant property of matter.  Unless some matter escapes the container, or new matter enters the container, the mass will remain constant.  The same number of atoms are inside and they weigh the same even if distributed differently.

Comment: "Note that neither the volume nor the density appear here. As long as the mass and the shape of the container are constant, so is the pressure." But pressure is constant in a liquid only when the weight of liquid is neglected which I don't find any relation here

Answer (score 0):

The pressure at a given depth below the surface is the one of the atmosphere above  + increments of $\rho(z)~ dz$. So the pressure at a given depth, which corresponds to the weight of the pile above, depends of the $\rho$ values encoutered above: all at 1 then all at 3, or all at 3 then all at 1 (not very steady ;-) ), or mix of average 2, does not give the same curve $P(z)$.

Besides, mixing sometime have strange effects, even if no chemical reaction occurs. E.g. alcool and water mixed occupy less volume than when separated. Which change the liquid level and the curve $P(z)$.